# I can't make Spring Boot and Hazelcast cluster work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hazelcast

I am trying to use a shared cache in a spring boot clustered app.
It seems that everything is working but when i tried to retrieve cached values from a second
instance of the app, it don't get it from cached values.

Seems like every app is working with his own cache and not sharing it.

I followed the guideline found here to setup a simple environment https://hazelcast.com/blog/spring-boot/

My code:

```
    Controller.java
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/public/testcache")
    public class TestCacheController {

        @Autowired
        BookService bookService;
        @GetMapping("/get/{isbn}")
        @ResponseBody
        public String getBookNameByIsbn(@PathVariable("isbn") String isbn) {
            return bookService.getBookNameByIsbn(isbn);
        }

        @GetMapping("/clear/cache")
        @ResponseBody
        public String clearCache() {
            bookService.deleteCache();
            return "done";
        }
    }


     BookService.java
     @Service
     public class BookService {
         @Cacheable("books")
         public String getBookNameByIsbn(String isbn) {
              return findBookInSlowSource(isbn);
         }

         private String findBookInSlowSource(String isbn) {
             // some long processing
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(3000);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             return "Sample Book "+isbn;
         }

         @CacheEvict(value = {"books"}, allEntries = true)
         public void deleteCache() {}
    }


    # hazelcast.yaml
    hazelcast:
        network:
          join:
            multicast:
              enabled: true
```

When i start the applications I always get the right output:

```
    Members {size:2, ver:2} [
        Member [192.168.178.107]:5702 - d53f2c3f-d66f-4ba3-bf8d-88d4935bde4e
        Member [192.168.178.107]:5701 - 69860793-c420-48d3-990c-d0c30a3a92d6 this
    ]
```

I tried:

1. running two Spring Boot apps on different ports
2. running two tomcat on different ports
3. replace the yaml configuration with java configuration

   ```
    Java Based Configuration
    @Configuration
    @EnableCaching
    public class CacheConfigurator {
        @Bean
        public Config config() {
            Config config=new Config();
            config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(true);
            return config;
       }
    }
   ```

Every time I get the same result, every app seems to cache on his own.

Additional information:

- I tried to use management center https://hazelcast.com/product-features/management-center/ and i can connect to cluster member, but i never see any value under "Map"
- I am wondering if the instances of hazelcast are launched but not used by spring boot that instead uses his own simple cache
- My application.properties is empty
- Spring boot version 2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Maybe each of your Spring Boot applications actually created two separate Hazelcast instances and it uses not clustered one for caching.

Please try to follow these guides:

- [Hazelcast Guides: Getting Started with Hazelcast using Spring Boot](https://guides.hazelcast.org/hazelcast-embedded-springboot/), it
- [Hazelcast Guides: Caching with Spring Boot and Hazelcast](https://guides.hazelcast.org/caching-springboot/)